# VSTO Word Extensions Knowing About Each Other

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I'm required to extend a Toolbar plugin for Word 2010 with a button that can detect documents using a companion C# Word 2010 document (template).

The scenario is: when I click a button in the toolbar (our custom toolbar), it will activate a Form that has been programmed in C#/WPF in the document.

Bing is failing me and I've been looking around the COM craziness. The "_CodeName" of the document is fairly obvious to find, but its a string, is there a .net plugin instance hiding somewhere on the document?

Is this even freakin' possible?

Comment: Do you want to have an application level addin ribbon but it should call the form which is part of document customization?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We've ended up moving all the code to the ribbon and using CustomAttributes to detect what form should show, working ok.